# Can't build my project in NetBeans, I am using Glassfish Server. Every time when I run I got an error the module has not been deployed

Tags: java, jsp, glassfish-4

GlassFish Server, deploy, SOCKS server general failure, false

```
D:\vaheed@i3\projects\recsol\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1048: The module has not been deployed. See the server log for details. BUILD FAILED`
```

Server Log

```
GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1  (13) startup time : Felix (5,662ms), startup services(39,218ms), total(44,880ms)
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 3ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:7676]
Info:   Registered   
com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@194ccbc as OSGi service registration:  
org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@18948cd.
Info:   JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL   
service:jmx:rmi://admin-PC:8686/jndi/rmi://admin-PC:8686/jmxrmi
```

Comment: The part of the server log you have added there doesn't contain any mention of the error you're seeing. Can you look through the server log, find and upload the error with the full stack trace included please.

Comment: Thank god! Finally i find the reason for this error.

Comment: Actually my problem is regarding with network connection.i set proxy for my internet...this is why i cant run netbeans.so people who got this error ,please check the proxy server .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check the proxy server settings

Comment: Could you elaborate?